# BTG wallet or exchange with BIP39 seed import

Tags: exchanges, seed, spv, bitcoin-gold, mnemonic-seed

Can anyone recommend a Bitcoin Gold exchange or SPV wallet for Linux that supports importing wallets from a BIP39 seed? The best I’ve found so far is a fork of Electrum that supports BTG for Windows or exchanges with no wallet import.

Comment: Take a look at the [Ecosystem](https://bitcoingold.org) section on the Bitcoin Gold website for a list of wallets and exchanges that support BTG

Comment: Thanks: I did have a quick look through there already. The wallets all seem to be for mobile (and, e.g., Freewallet hides away the technicalities) and of the exchanges I checked, many were no longer supporting BTG and none (that I saw) allowed wallet import :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't answer the question directly, but [Coinomi](https://coinomi.com) running in [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com) works and allows restoration from a BIP39 seed, per the instructions given here:

https://medium.com/@coinomi/collecting-your-free-bitcoin-gold-btg-coins-da937d4255d1

Genymotion can run under Linux, so while it's a bit of work, one can achieve the desired outcome using this method.

Comment: Annoyingly, when I managed to reclaim my BTG address, it appears that the contents had been [stolen](http://btgexp.com/address/GRQvbtm5eWPFfjR8Zw7GMTnbRWoGVZTGTF)! Fortunately, I had moved my BTC already, to avoid just this scenario, but let this be a warning to others. The only other place I tried the seed was an online wallet -- admittedly a stupid move, on my part -- which, judging by my history, was mybtgwallet.com. That site is now down and giving a certificate error, so I think there's quite a high probability it was a phishing expedition :(

Comment: Live and learn, I suppose... https://bitcoingold.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Statement-on-MYBTGWALLET.pdf