# What is the secure, self-hosted wallet to redeem BTG (Bitcoin Gold)?

Tags: wallet, seed, bitcoin-gold, mnemonic-seed

## Hacking and being hacked is not cool

[image]

I'm looking for a decent solution to redeem BTG.

## Ideally self-hosted and open source.

I have 12 words seed phrase, BIP39, deterministic derivation path, etc...

**Related:** [Claiming my BTG from my BTC private key](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/63088/claiming-my-btg-from-my-btc-private-key/63227#63227)

They suggest using offline version of https://www.bitaddress.org/ to extrac the `private key` and then https://medium.com/@coinomi/collecting-your-free-bitcoin-gold-btg-coins-da937d4255d1

---

**Relevant / irrelevant detail:** after the snapshot took place, I've sent some BTC to another address. I believe I should still own the corresponding amount of BTG.

For security reasons I'll first transfer my current BTC to a new SegWit address I'm holding, and only then start experimenting with BTG.

---

**Related:** [BTG wallet or exchange with BIP39 seed import](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/62250/btg-wallet-or-exchange-with-bip39-seed-import)

#### Your recommendation with regards to BTG is greatly appreciated.

**Research:** https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=btg.org.freewallet.app
[image]

*(surely it's not only me who has ponders this question)*

Answer (score 1):

> Ideally self-hosted and open source.

State of the blockchain, crypto, whole ecosystem - early days - no ideal solutions - skilled developers are in extremely high demand and (to be honest) I didn't expect to find such tool.

With that said - first I moved actual BTC to another address.

Then - using the seed I was able to follow instructions here: https://coinsutra.com/claim-bitcoin-gold-btg/ *(very good write up, **THANKS**)*

## In essence:

- install Coinomi app *(currently Android only)*
- restore wallet
- put your phrase *(don't tick BIP39)*
- add BTC *(optionally, I first added BTC so that I could easily verify that balance is recognised)*
- add BTG - advanced - `M/44H/0H/0H` *(important, defaults are not smart)*
- **profit**

---

I happened to keep BTC at blockchain.info (not anymore) so I had access to the 12 words seed - that was easy. There is a number of questions about claiming BTG from other type of the wallets - my first thought are leading towards `bounty-smart-contract-fication` - put some money in the pot and hire developers - so that whales can get their 5% dividend without risking much.

In my case - I enjoy playing, educating, experimenting. It was time well spent - I believe so.

Answer (score 0):

- Coinomi (Warning: Not open source)
- [Freewallet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=btg.org.freewallet.app&referrer=af_tranid%3DV05zeVmKAK9sZKKSG0YHdA%26pid%3Dfreewalletsite%26utm_source%3Dfreewalletsite) (Warning: You don't control your private keys!)
- [Guarda](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.guarda.btg)
- BitPie ([iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bitpie-bitcoin-wallet/id1168568820), [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bitpie)) (Warning: Not open source)

Redeem? Coinomi!

Comment: Yeah, I'm following these instructions now: https://coinsutra.com/claim-bitcoin-gold-btg/ - tried once, reset app data, now trying again...

Answer (score -1):

MCCCS, I may add electrum gold, which is an electrum for BTG instead of btc,

You can find it here at https://electrumgold.org/

Of course you need to prove you are the owner of the wallet either by seed or by private keys

Comment: This site looks very much like a scam; the "Explore Source Code" text is not a link, or even plain text; it's an image!